# Using varnish-counters MAIN.* in VCL

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Is it possible to use varnish-counters in VCL in conditions?

I would like to write a condition based on current value of  MAIN.backend_conn but I cannot figure out, whether can I use statistics in VCL even in inline C.

## Current Solution

Now I am using configuration like this:

```
backend default {
    .host = "192.168.122.11";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/check-connections.php";
        .interval = 1s;
        .threshold = 4;
    }
}

backend sessionWorker {
    .host = "192.168.122.11";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/other-probe";
        .interval = 5s;
        .threshold = 2;
    }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "(^|;\s*)(SESS=)" || std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        set req.backend_hint = sessionWorker;
    } else {
        return (synth(503, "Server overloaded"));
    }
}
```

check-connections.php reads nginx status - active connections and triggers an error, if there are more active connections:

```
if ($active > 10) {
    http_response_code(502);
} else {
    http_response_code(200);
}
```

I would like to find a solution how to replace std.healty(req.backend_hint) with current connections (VBE.conn) to the backend directly in the VCL.

Answer (score 0):

There are some counters implemented already. Like `bereq.retries`:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
  if (beresp.status == 503 && bereq.retries < 5 ) {
    return(retry);
  }
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
  if (beresp.status == 503 && bereq.retries == 5) {
    synthetic(std.fileread("/path/to/my/file/varnish503.html"));
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

Maybe this is already what you need. Otherwise [here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnish-counters.html) is a list of other build in counters.

Comment: bereq.retries is not what I am looking for. I know, that there are few [variables available in VCL](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vcl.html#variables) but I would like to use [VBE.conn](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnish-counters.html#per-backend-counters-vbe) from the list of available counters. But I don't know how to work with that counters in VCL.